# How to get a single field from Firestore document without using Event Listener?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

This code is working, but not the way I want, I need a way to extract a single value ("secret-key") into the string "users" without using the Event listener because I need a way to send this string variable to another function, so it can be encrypted. I want the code inside the comment lines to work, or something like that.

```
 public void getData() {

        String currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
        DocumentReference user = fStore.collection("Users").document(currentUser);
        //I WANT THIS TO WORK/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        String users = fStore.collection("Users").document(currentUser).get("secretKey").toString();
        Log.d("LOGGER", users.toString());
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        user.addSnapshotListener(this, new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot value, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {
                if (value.exists()){

                    String secretKey = value.getString("secretKey");
                    String groupID = value.getString("groupID");
                    String data = secretKey +":::"+ groupID;

                    StringBuilder textToSend = new StringBuilder();
                    textToSend.append(data);
                    MultiFormatWriter multiFormatWriter = new MultiFormatWriter();
                    try {
                        BitMatrix bitMatrix = multiFormatWriter.encode(textToSend.toString(), BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, 600, 600);
                        BarcodeEncoder barcodeEncoder = new BarcodeEncoder();
                        Bitmap bitmap = barcodeEncoder.createBitmap(bitMatrix);

                        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                        imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    } catch (WriterException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                }

            }
        });
    }
```

Please help!
Another way of seeing this problem is:
I need a way to send the string 'data' to another function.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the Task returned by `get()` to asynchronously receive the contents of the document, as you see in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document).  You can't just call `toString()` on it.  Here is what's shown in that link:

```
DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("cities").document("SF");
docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
            if (document.exists()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot data: " + document.getData());
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "No such document");
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", task.getException());
        }
    }
});
```

It doesn't really get any shorter than that.

You can use the DocumentSnapshot object to get the single field out of the document that you need.  There is no API for getting only a single field - you must read the entire document, then find the field you want from it.

Comment: If I use that I can't send the values of 'task' to another function or can I?

Comment: You can do whatever you want inside that callback.  You can call another function from there if you want.

Comment: I mean, can I extract the respective field, and send it in a string value to another function?

Comment: Sure, you can call other functions and pass the contents of the document as a parameter.

Comment: How? It is not possible because onComplete is void it cant return a value String

Comment: You don't return the value.  You **call** another function from within the callback.  Or you adopt Kotlin and coroutines to make the syntax easier.  This is how asynchronous programming works.

Comment: So my only option is to build every function that I need inside the onComplete?

Comment: You can build one function that can receive everything you need to do next, after the query is complete.  That function can call other functions too, if you want.  Or you can take up another form of asynchronous programming, such as LiveData.